# Add date range on button click with datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying open a calendar with datepicker on button click, and have the date go into the sibling text box when chosen. I need to be able to do this for two different text boxes.

Here is what I have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/zEper/

Comment: So you want the date entered into text box one to go into text box two?

Comment: It depends. It shouldgo into the text box of the corresponding button.

Comment: Oh right, well yeh you don't need the buttons. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the jQuery UI with that jsfiddle. Try the following:

```
<div>
    <label>Start</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
</div>

<div>
    <label>End</label>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
</div>
```

And your JS:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "link to your button here",
    buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

Things to note: you don't need to add the button, the datepicker will do that for you - you'll need to add a link to a button image. If you don't like this then you could just remove the bottonImage reference.

All of this has been taken from the jQuery datepicker UI documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#options)

**EDIT:**
Fixed up closing tags for html elements, fixed in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zEper/5/)

Comment: updated base off of your suggestion, but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/zEper/3/

Comment: +1 for using buttons like he asked, I should read the question better!

Comment: Might want to fix up the closing tags in your example though.